# How to fix 'Syntax error on token "else", delete this token'?

Tags: java, if-statement

```
if (option10.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) { // if they want to pay
                        System.out.println("Confirmation ID: U1000");
                        System.out.println ("Items shipped to: " + user.getUsername());
                        try {
                            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("Cart_"+user.getUsername()+".txt");
                            writer.print("");
                            writer.close();
                        } 
                        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            System.out.print ("File not found");
                        }

                        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
                            int itemFlag=0;
                            for (int j = 0; j < readableProducts.size(); j++) {
                                itemR = readableProducts.get(j);
                                if (itemR.getTitle().compareTo((temp[i].split(", "))[1])==0) {                              
                                    // add item to ItemsBought.txt
                                    addItem(itemR.getTitle(), itemR.getBasePrice(), itemR.getType(), itemR.getQuantity());
                                    itemFlag=1;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            if (itemFlag == 0) {
                                for (int j = 0; j < audioProducts.size(); j++) {
                                    itemA = audioProducts.get(j);
                                    if (itemA.getTitle().compareTo((temp[i].split(", "))[1])==0) {                                  
                                        // add item to ItemsBought.txt
                                        addItem(itemA.getTitle(), itemA.getBasePrice(), itemA.getType(), itemA.getQuantity());
                                        itemFlag=1;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                        changeCurrentPage(1);
                    else 
                        changeCurrentPage(5);
```

This is a part of a project I'm doing at university. It's an e-commerce application where the last page is billing info. The program asks the user if he wants to pay, and if the user says "yes", the program writes the details of his items purchased into a file. Then his shopping cart is cleared and he is taken to page(1). Else, he is taken to page 5.

The error is for the last else. How do I get rid of it? 
I think all my brackets and semicolons are in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The semicolon before the `changeCurrentPage(1);` is closing the `if` at the top, leaving your `else` statement floating. Move the the semicolon down a line to be before the `else`.